# Getting a new PC built and I have some questions

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, power-supply, computer-building

In a couple of weeks I will get a new PC built and I wanted to ask if I could re-use some of the old components in the new one, since I'm on a 600- 650 euro budget. The old parts were regulary cleaned of dust.
The parts that I wanted to re-use are:

-Storage(1TB hard drive)

-PSU MSTech ATX 650W

-Memory 8gigs of RAM(DDR3 Dual channel)

Below is a link to the parts that I would like to buy new:

http://pcpartpicker.com/p/svZLbv  (The list does not include the case and other components).

If someone could check if all the parts would work together and/or if I should get something else instead. I would like to stick with the GPU I have listed. Also I will not need an extra CPU cooler since it's already included in the CPU i have listed right?

Answer (score 1):

1) Unless your Hard Drive has a different interface than SATA, it's ok

2) Your PSU is ok, 650W are enough for the system you listed

3) The RAM is DDR3 just like your Motherboard, so it's ok

4) Yes, the CPU package contains a stock cooler

Comment: The assumption all DDR3 will work is a flaw in logic and MAY damage a system.

Answer (score -1):

To assume the Hdd is still in decent shape  --not to old or high in read/write cycles sure could reuse it, same goes for the PSU  ---You don't mention the speed of the DDR3  but if its new-ish (2011 or newer) should be fine that particular board supports  the following speeds

```
 DDR3-1333 / 1600 / 1866 / 2133 / 2400 / 2800 / 2933 / 3100
```

So looks like you did a good job on the picking parts side  -- as for the additional CPU cooler that depends on how you plan to use it but as it has one built in to the cpu housing a second one is **NOT** obligatory